# How to install afd debugger in linux?

Tags: linux, debugging

I am learning about assembly languages. I have install **nasm** assembler in ubuntu 15.04. I have tried to find **afo**(advance full screen debug) debugger but I didn't get it.

How can i install it on my machine?

Comment: `afd` seems to be an old debugger for dos. If you really want that, install it into `dosbox`.

Comment: try a few alternatives - WDASM aka win32dasm, a disassembler (for DOS), and OllyDbg - a nice debugger that works fine under modern windows machiens.

Comment: if all else fails, use `gdb` as your debugger :)

Comment: I know gdb very well. I need of afo debugger.